# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column or name

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext, sql-update, android-sqlite, multiple-columns

when i run my application it shows no such column. I want to update the teacher profile in my application. i have change database_name, table_name, column_name and checkout each and everything, I don't know what is wrong with update query please help out, I always get this error while updating query
what is best solution and alternative ways to solve it

Thanks in advance

```
public class DatabaseTeacher extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String databasename="Teacher";

    public static final String Teacher_table="Teacher_table";

    public static final String Teacher_name="Name";
    public static final String Teacher_Email_ID="Email";
    public static final String Teacher_Password="Password";
    public static final String Teacher_Confirm_Password="ConfirmPassword";
    public static final String Teacher_Phone_number="Phone";
    public static final String Teacher_Branch="Branch";
    public static final String Teacher_Subject="Subject";
    public static final int versioncode=1;

    public DatabaseTeacher(Context context){
        super(
                context,
                databasename,
                null,
                versioncode);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

        String teacher_query;
        teacher_query="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+Teacher_table+"(Name TEXT,Email TEXT PRIMARY KEY,Password TEXT,ConfirmPassword TEXT,Phone TEXT,Branch TEXT,Subject TEXT)";
        database.execSQL(teacher_query);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        String teacher_query;
        teacher_query= "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Teacher_table;
        database.execSQL(teacher_query);

    }

    public boolean Teacher_Data(String Name,String Email,String Password,String ConfirmPassword,String Phone,String Branch,String Subject){
        SQLiteDatabase db1=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

        cv.put(Teacher_name,Name);
        cv.put(Teacher_Email_ID,Email);
        cv.put(Teacher_Password,Password);
        cv.put(Teacher_Confirm_Password,ConfirmPassword);
        cv.put(Teacher_Phone_number,Phone);
        cv.put(Teacher_Branch,Branch);
        cv.put(Teacher_Subject,Subject);

        long result=db1.insert(Teacher_table,null,cv);
        if(result==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    public Cursor TeacherData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db1=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db1.rawQuery("select * from "+Teacher_table,null);
        return res;
    }
 public Boolean update(String Name,String Email,String Password,String ConfirmPassword,String Phone,String Branch,String Subject){

        ContentValues args= new ContentValues();
        args.put(Teacher_name,Name);
        args.put(Teacher_Email_ID,Email);
        args.put(Teacher_Password,Password);
        args.put(Teacher_Confirm_Password,ConfirmPassword);
        args.put(Teacher_Phone_number,Phone);
        args.put(Teacher_Branch,Branch);
        args.put(Teacher_Subject,Subject);


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int res = db.update(Teacher_table,args,Teacher_name + "=" + Name,null);
        return res>0;

    }
```

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher_profile);


         editname=findViewById(R.id.teachername);
         editemail=findViewById(R.id.teacheremail);
         editpassword=findViewById(R.id.teacherpassword);
         editconfirm=findViewById(R.id.teacherconfirm);
         editphone=findViewById(R.id.teacherphone);
         editbranch=findViewById(R.id.teacherbranch);
         editsubject=findViewById(R.id.teachersubject);
         btnteacherupdate=findViewById(R.id.btnteacherupdate);

        dbh = new DatabaseTeacher(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase=dbh.getReadableDatabase();
        res=dbh.TeacherData();

        if(res.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                String name,email,password,confirm,phone,branch,subject;

                name= res.getString(0);
                email=res.getString(1);
                password=res.getString(2);
                confirm=res.getString(3);
                phone=res.getString(4);
                branch=res.getString(5);
                subject=res.getString(6);


                editname.setText(name);
                editemail.setText(email);
                editpassword.setText(password);
                editconfirm.setText(confirm);
                editphone.setText(phone);
                editbranch.setText(branch);
                editsubject.setText(subject);


            }while(res.moveToNext());
        }


        btnteacherupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try{
                    String name=  editname.getText().toString().trim();
                    String email=  editemail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String password= editpassword.getText().toString().trim();
                    String confirm= editconfirm.getText().toString().trim();
                    String phone =editphone.getText().toString().trim();
                    String branch=editbranch.getText().toString().trim();
                    String subject=editsubject.getText().toString().trim();




                    //Save into DBS
                    dbh.update(name,email,password,confirm,phone,branch,subject);

                    Toast.makeText(TeacherProfileActivity.this, "Modified Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dbh.close();
                    startActivity(new Intent(TeacherProfileActivity.this, StudentHomeActivity.class));
                    finish();

                }catch (Exception e){

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
logcat

W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Hshs (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE Teacher_table SET Email=?,Phone=?,Branch=?,Subject=?,Name=?,Password=?,ConfirmPassword=? WHERE Name=Hshs, (OS error - 11:Try again)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:948)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:559)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1969)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1912)
        at com.example.collegecongruency.Database.DatabaseTeacher.update(DatabaseTeacher.java:102)
        at com.example.collegecongruency.TeacherProfileActivity$1.onClick(TeacherProfileActivity.java:89)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that you are passing a value as if it were a column name (and hence the error), that is it is a string/text value that is not enclosed in single quotes (which are used to distinguish text from entity names (columns, tables views etc)).

Use :-

```
int res = db.update(Teacher_table,args,Teacher_name + "='" + Name + "'",null);
```

Or better :-

```
int res = db.update(Teacher_table,args,Teacher_name + "=?",new String[]{name});
```

- The latter puts the quotes around the value and protects against SQLInjection attacks.
- the ? represents a bound value i.e. one that is replaced according to the values via the 4th parameter. The 3rd parameter being an array of Strings each will replace the repective ? in the where clause (3rd parameter)

Comment: Thank you sir, what you said was correct when i click on update button it successfully updating but some field are not updating why like that here name is not updating.

Comment: @sahanavalli only if an existing name is entered will it update a row. If a non-existant name is entered then there will be no row to be updated. Typically you would select the name from the names available in the database, perhaps using a spinner.